# Sitting pillows of a couch keeps moving from place

Tags: cleaning, comfort, organization, furniture

I have a couch, and the sitting pillows always move from their place after a few days and I need to rearrange them.

I thought about using a strong [velcro](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=velcro&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL794IL794&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie8d3hsrfbAhXmAsAKHRHuA0AQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=898), but I'm not sure it will do the work.

Any idea how can I make the pillows stick into place?
It shouldn't be permanent in a way that won't let me take out the pillows for cleaning.

### Photos:

- This is how it looks when it moved:

  [image]
- From the back:

  [image]
- From the bottom:

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

The existing surface of the couch (under the cushions) looks smooth and possibly it interacts with the existing surface of the bottom of the cushion. Acting one against the other might cause the cushion creep.
Here are some things to try:

1. Spread a towel or rough surfaced fabric under all the cushions in the couch. The towel surface between the existing surfaces might help.
2. Rotate the cushions 180° so the pattern is similarly aligned. Perhaps the "grain" or direction of the cloth weave has some effect on cushion creep.
3. Flip the cushion over if the cushion design allows, top-for-bottom.
4. Use a length of adhesive Rug-Tape along the leading edge of the lip of the couch. Place it an inch or so in so that it remains out of sight.

Answer (score 1):

Velcro holds very well. I've seen people attaching heavy boards to a wall with velcro and there was no indication whatsoever that they might fall.

Another thing that came to my mind was using some of that anti-slip underlay they spread under rugs and carpets (it is fairly cheap), but I would personaly go for the velcro.